# Wait for all the select lists to load jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, selectlist

I have two select lists and the second one depends on the first. I would like to allow the second select list to load and then fire some alerts after that. What is the best way to achieve this using jQuery?

For eg: The second list gets populated in the following manner below:

- 1 - a,b,c
- 2 - b,c,d
- 3 - a,c,d
- 4 - a,b

Meaning that if someone selects 1 in the first picklist, the second one is loaded with options a,b,c.

```js
$("#first").change(function() {  // bind a change event:
      refreshsecond(document.theForm);
    }).change(); // and trigger a "change" event immediately


function refreshsecond(form)
{
var length = $('#second').children('option').length;

alert("Length is :" + length);
}
```

```html
<select id="first" name="firstName">
 <option value='1'>1</option> 
<option value='2'>2</option>   
<option value='3'>3</option> 
<option value='4'>4</option>   
</select>

<select id="second" name="secondName">
    <option value='a'>a</option>
    <option value='b'>b</option>  
    <option value='c'>c</option>
    <option value='d'>d</option>  
    </select>
```

Comment: You need to show what you have attempted :)

Comment: *"the second one depends on the first"* - in what way? I don't understand how this is supposed to function, does the first list add something to the second one?

Comment: So if someone selects 1 in the first picklist, the second one is loaded with options a,b,c. Just an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other than having `#second` load elements in a certain way a better idea is to just add and replace to the elements HTML. Meaning that we start with `#second` being empty and change the `<option>` items based on the first select box's value. For example:

```js
$("#first").change(function() { 

    if($(this).val() == 1) 
        $("#second").html(loadValues(['a','b','c']));
    else if($(this).val() == 2) 
        $("#second").html(loadValues(['b','c','d']));
    else if($(this).val() == 3) 
        $("#second").html(loadValues(['a','c','d']));  
    else if($(this).val() == 4) 
        $("#second").html(loadValues(['a','b']));

    var length = $('#second').children('option').length;
    alert("Length is :" + length); 
   
}).change();
    
function loadValues(ArrValues){
    var string = "";
    for(var i = 0; i < ArrValues.length; i++)
        string += "<option value='"+ArrValues[i]+"'>"+ArrValues[i]+"</option>";
    return string;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="first" name="firstName">
  <option value='1'>1</option> 
  <option value='2'>2</option>   
  <option value='3'>3</option> 
  <option value='4'>4</option>   
</select>

<select id="second" name="secondName">
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's dependent on the user selecting one in the first dropdown, you simply need to attach an onChange handler to the first dropdown list.

For example

```
$('#first').change(function() { 
 //do your stuff here to second dropdown list.
});
```

Take a look at http://api.jquery.com/change/ for more details.

Comment: Yes I have done that but how do I wait till the second list is loaded as well?

Comment: Sorry what do you mean by "loaded"?  Are you using an ajax call to load the list entries?